# Abnormal exit when executing 'docker run..' for golang

Tags: go, docker

Not sure why this is happening, when I run

```
docker build –t my-app .

docker run -p 8000:8000 -d my-app
```

it immediately exits

`docker ps -a` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
b7ede6791baf        my-app              "./app"             8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 7 seconds ago                       adoring_einstein
```

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN go build ./app.go

CMD ["./app"]
```

I'm on Mac.

Any suggestions and/or help would be great, thx in advance.

Comment: oh why the -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

oops I should of ran `-it` found my issue, it's a path issue with my templates... dump:

> panic: open
>   /go/src/github.com/XXXXXX/XXXXX/templates/layout/_base.html: no such
>   file or directory
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: html/template.Must(0x0, 0x92fcc0, 0xc42006af90,
>   0x0)  /usr/local/go/src/html/template/template.go:360 +0x54
>   main.loadTemplates()  /app/src/github.com/username/app/main.go:119
>   +0x1a7 main.init.1()  /app/src/github.com/username/app/main.go:46 +0x15b main.init()  /app/src/github.com/username/app/main.go:136 +0x67